# Is it possible in bootstrap or HTML to only accept string as input in forms?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want the input to username as string only. Is it possible or should I use Formik?

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputText">UserName</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTextl1" aria-describedby="textHelp" placeholder="Enter Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: You should check for this in the backend, you can do it with a simple regex

Comment: All data that comes from an html form is in string format. I guess you want the username to be a collection of chars, right? Then just use the pattern and required attributes. There is absolutely no need to use another library or framework for that. All you need is the HTML5 constraint validation API and some validation in the backend.

Comment: @Marcel Thanks,it helps :-) I'll use pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pattern on clientside to allow only certain characters:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-Z]" class="form-control" id="usernaame" aria-describedby="textHelp" placeholder="Enter Username">
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include `pattern` attribute to your username `input` field

```
 pattern="[a-zA-Z]*"
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputText">UserName</label>
    <input type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]*" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTextl1" aria-describedby="textHelp" placeholder="Enter Username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do on `client` side easily with `JS` function working below.

Its checking for only letters allowed if you enter number or other characters it will show an `alert`.

charCode is JS which which check the keys entered by user and if matches the criteria that we had set which is letters only it will return `true` and user will able to type a username OR return `false` and alert if you enter number or other characters.

```js
function lettersOnlyAllowed() {
  var charCode = event.keyCode;
  if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || charCode == 8) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Please enter letters only')
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputText">UserName</label>
    <input type="text" onkeypress="return lettersOnlyAllowed(event);" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTextl1" aria-describedby="textHelp" placeholder="Enter Username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.